# Stop loop in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I need help to stop a loop in discord.js. I don't know what to do to stop the loop.

```js
let sec = 5;
let timer = setInterval(function() {
  if (command = "8") message.channel.send("ddd");
}, sec * 1000);

if (command = "stoploop") clearInterval(timer);
```

My problem is that `clearInterval` is not defined.

Comment: Could you please add the error you get into the question

Answer (score 4):

In `if (condition)` statements, you can't use `=`. This is used to assign a new value to a variable, property or anything else.

The is equal to selectors are:

- `==` for equal to.
- `===` for equal to of the same type.

```js
1 == '1' // returns true
1 === '1' // returns false
```

Comment: Good explanatory answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
client.on ('message', async message => {
  var prefix = "=",
      command = message.content.slice (prefix.length).split (" ")[0],
      sec = 5;
  switch (command) {
    case "startloop":
      if (message.channel.loop) return message.channel.send ('loop is already started');
      else message.channel.loop = setInterval (() => message.channel.send ('ddd'), sec * 1000);
      break;
    case "stoploop":
      if (!message.channel.loop) return message.channel.send ('no loop to stop lol');
      else {
        clearInterval (message.channel.loop);
        message.channel.loop = false;
      }
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you add text to explain how this code answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let sec = 5;
let timer = setInterval(function() {
  if (command = "8") message.channel.send("ddd");
}, sec * 1000);

if (command = "stoploop") clearTimeout(timer);
```

The reason why you were getting an error is because clearInterval() is not a function in JavaScript. The function I believe you are looking for is clearTimeout().

Answer (score 0):

I will store interval in Client:

```js
let sec = 5;
message.client.variables.timer = setInterval(function() {
  if (command = "8") message.channel.send("ddd");
}, sec * 1000);

//When you want to stop the loop
clearInterval(message.client.variables.timer);
```

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn't use `setInterval`, since discord.js is an **event driven** library. You should code as the developer of discord.js intended to. use this instead:

```
this.client.on('ready', () => {
    //Runs when discord bot is fully loaded.
    this.client.on('message', async (msg) => {
        //Runs when a message was sent to the channel.
        let parseTokens = yourCommandParser(msg.content); //Parses your command.
        executeYourCommand(parseTokens);
    });
});
```

I highly recommend you to learn how to write clean and better code, and then study about compilation and language parsing, before making a discord bot with commands.

Hope this helps! (^ w ^)

**Afterthought:** `setInterval` is also insecure, don't use it anywhere where you would have a user input. There are some exploits that are possible through `setInterval` the same way you'd hack a website that uses `eval` to execute code. Never ever use `setInterval` / `setTimeout` and `eval` in discord bots. For more info, search for `server side injection`.
Here's some example of that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68870077/15017928