# I need example to stopping loop in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I want to finish the loop or limit messages.

I dont know what to do to stop the loop.
please help

For example I want to do

```
let timer = setInterval(function(){    
if(command = "loop")
message.channel.send("test")
       }, sec * 1000)
if(command = "stoploop")
//i need example to stopping the loop
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need help to stop loop in discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54650583/i-need-help-to-stop-loop-in-discord-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [clearInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) to stop a running interval.

```js
let timer = setInterval(function() {
  if(command === "loop")
    message.channel.send("test")
}, sec * 1000)

if(command === "stoploop") {
  clearInterval(timer);
}
```

Please keep in mind that sending a message to a channel every second is every abusive to Discord's API. Doing such behavior for too long will probably make Discord ban your bot because of API abuse.

Comment: Hey Ishidres when i do !stoploop the loop dont stop. I dont know why please help.

Comment: Are there any error logs in the console? Is timer accessable in the current scope? Try making timer global by defining it outside any scope.

Comment: The value of 'command' might be undefined in the scope where you check if command === "loop". Try debugging the application by logging the value of 'command'.

Comment: I did
```
let timer = setInterval(function() {
    if(command === "loop")
    message.channel.send("test")
}, 3 * 1000)
if(command === "stoploop"){
  clearInterval(timer),message.channel.send("**sto..**")
  console.log(`${command} command ```
when i do !stoploop this write in the console !stoploop command